# Tibco- EMS Queues

Tags: tibco, tibco-ems, ems

my requirement is to set-up EMS setting as below.. Is this feasible?
1. The parent EMS queue.
2. The child EMS listened by Tibco BW Engine.

The EMS queue will receive thousands of messages every minute.. parent queue has to pile up the messages and passes limited messages to child queue say 1000 is the limit.. I.e child queue should have 1000 messages and rest of the messages should be in parent queue.. Once the thousand messages in child queue is consumed by Tibco BW, parent queue to send next thousand messages to the child queue.. Is this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two ways:

1 - To do exactly what you suggest, you would need a BusinessWorks "control" component, reacting to a signal sent from the "emptying" of the child queue, and transferring exactly 1000 messages from parent to child (via a transaction and with persistence if you can't loose any messages). I have no idea why you would do that... but this answers to the requirements

2 - Assuming that your question is related to pacing of the outbound messages (child queue) WITHOUT pacing the inbound messages (parent queue), then I suggest something else : Use the flowControl EMS Destination property, and limit the flow of message another way. By default, if you implement a flowControl of 10000KB with messages of an average of 10KB, then you should have a similar limit as the one you requested. The plan would then be to bridge your "parent" to your "child", and to implement flow control on both destinations (with different values) AND the bridge itself (as stated in the "Destination Bridges and Flow Control" section of the user guide).

Comment: Thanks.. I ll try the suggestions.. I understood that if we have BW process with flow limit control and the incoming message is very high.. The BW process will close the message consumer and consume messages only after some threshold messages are processes.. Every time EMS server will need to do cache and re priorities the messages to send the queue.. So if i limited messages in the queue.. Thought it will be faster.. Pls refer  http://stackoverflow.com/q/28544050/889457

Comment: @GKN I beleive your struggle witht BW flowLimit will be greatly improved if you leverage EMS flowControl. Tell me how it goes... and vote up if you really liked the suggestions ;-)

Comment: I was working on this but our IFS team, migrated TIBCO EMS from 5.* to 8.*, where the issue resolved automatically. Thanks for your feedback, it really shown me some light :)